# Greying out a checkbox when another is checked

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a list of delivery checkboxes one for deliver to this address and another for deliver to a separate address, I basically want to make it so once one has been checked the other can not be checked out (perhaps by greying it out or something along those lines)

Please be aware that both boxes use the same controls.

Comment: You should use radio button for mutually exclusive options.

Comment: Are you using win forms or WPF or...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Listen to the first CheckBox's CheckedChanged event with a method like this one:

```
private void checkBox1_checkedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.checkBox2.Enabled = !this.checkBox1.Checked;

    // If you want it to be unchecked as well as grayed out,
    // then have this code as well:
    if (!this.checkBox2.Enabled)
    {
        this.checkBox2.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

But you should consider using RadioButtons instead of CheckBoxes, if it logically fits to your needs.

Comment: That won't work.  It has to be `checkBox2.IsEnabled` and `checkBox2.IsChecked`, not `.Enabled` or `.Checked`...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code,

```
checkboxToBeGreyed.Enabled = false;
```

You have write this code in other checkbox's checked event . Hope this helps.